# Implementing a TI antenna design on an existing PCB

Tags: pcb, antenna, pcb-antenna

I'm currently working on a PCB that processes certain sensor measurements. These measurements are then periodically transmitted over the LoRaWAN network (868MHz). I'm using an RFM95 module with an SMA connector and an 868MHz external antenna. This works fine but I'd like to incorporate the antenna into the PCB. I've done some research but I'm very new to antenna technology and I ran into some problems.

I've decided that I want to prototype with [Texas Instruments' recommended antenna design](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra227e/swra227e.pdf) for the 868MHz band. Whilst reading the design note I came across very specific antenna measurements (obviously), but also measurements for the ground plane located on the bottom side as visible in the image below.

[image]

However, I'm having difficulty understanding what I CAN and CAN'T do with this ground plane. As I'm looking to incorporate this into an existing PCB, I'm wondering whether I can populate the ground plane area with components or not. Furthermore, I'm wondering whether I can extend the ground plane as the current PCB is larger than 63mm x 43mm.

> **Actual question:** Can I extend the ground plane and place components on it as I would do in a regular PCB design.

Comment: What's on the other side of the board?  Is it another ground plane?  And the SMA connector?

Comment: if you can find the document with the design details all that information should be given

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I imagine that you can do whatever you want in the pink zone so long as you keep all the conductors as-is in the area used by the antenna (green/white zone).

As for ground plane the image is a two layer board and the plane under the microstrip (the vertical; part above the socket) should be retained at the same distance to maintain the impedance match.

If you are using more layers the microstrip could be redesigned for a closer ground plane allowing the other side of the PCB to be populated behind the microstrip.

The zig-zag antenna uses both sides of the board so you can't place components behind it and should not place any conductors close to it.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive reply. If the microstrip is used for impedance matching, does this mean that I cannot extend the length of the trace? I'm asking this because it would otherwise seem that my RF receiver IC has to be in the location of the SMA connector.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, going with a larger ground plane won't hurt the design.  Try to keep the ground plane solid (ie, no components or traces) on at least one layer.  This will mean putting all components, at least near the antenna, on the other layer.  You may have to go with a 4 layer board to make the routing a bit easier.  TI has reference designs that use this antenna with the radio on the same PCB.  You can check out their launch pads to see how they are implemented. http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00816